# SQL to count number for each value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query and I want to be able to count the total number of priorities which has values set to low, medium, high or unspecified.

Currently it counts to a maximum of 13 rows, i'd expect there to be multiple columns with counts such as... 2, 4, 0

Code:

```
 SELECT c.Name, COUNT(*) as Count_By_Priority, 
 CASE WHEN cb.Priority = 0 THEN "Unspecified" WHEN cb.Priority = 1 THEN "Low" WHEN cb.Priority = 2 THEN "Medium" WHEN cb.Priority = 3 THEN "High" END as PriorityNumber 
 FROM TABLE 1 cb 
 LEFT JOIN Co c ON c.Id = cb.Id 
 WHERE c.Name LIKE %Name%" 
 GROUP BY c.Id;
```

It seems to print "Unspecified" for the priority keys when I would be expecting low or alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you can just change your group by clause to group by `c.Id`, then `PriorityNumber`:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name,
    COUNT(*) as Count_By_Priority,
    CASE 
        WHEN cb.Priority = 0 THEN "Unspecified"
        WHEN cb.Priority = 1 THEN "Low"
        WHEN cb.Priority = 2 THEN "Medium"
        WHEN cb.Priority = 3 THEN "High" 
    END as PriorityNumber
FROM TABLE 1 cb 
LEFT JOIN Co c 
ON c.Id = cb.Id
WHERE c.Name LIKE %Name%"
GROUP BY c.Id, PriorityNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT c.Name, COUNT(*) as Count_By_Priority,
CASE WHEN cb.Priority = 0 THEN "Unspecified" 
WHEN cb.Priority = 1 THEN "Low" 
WHEN cb.Priority = 2 THEN "Medium" 
WHEN cb.Priority = 3 THEN "High" END as PriorityNumber 

FROM TABLE 1 cb LEFT JOIN Co c ON c.Id = cb.Id 

WHERE c.Name LIKE %Name%" 

GROUP BY c.Name,PriorityNumber ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using aggregation, but your `SELECT` is inconsistent with your `GROUP BY`.  I think you intend something like:

```
SELECT c.Name, COUNT(*) as Count_By_Priority, 
       (CASE WHEN MAX(cb.Priority) = 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
             WHEN MAX(cb.Priority) = 1 THEN 'Low'
             WHEN MAX(cb.Priority) = 2 THEN 'Medium'
             WHEN MAX(cb.Priority) = 3 THEN 'High'
        END) as PriorityNumber 
FROM TABLE 1 cb LEFT JOIN
     Co c
     ON c.Id = cb.Id 
WHERE c.Name LIKE '%Name%'
GROUP BY c.Id;
```

I'm not sure if you want `MAX()` or `MIN()` but `MAX()` makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a count of each priority in a separate column use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT c.Name, 
 sum(CASE WHEN cb.Priority = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as "Unspecified" 
 sum(case WHEN cb.Priority = 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) as "Low" 
 sum(case WHEN cb.Priority = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) as "Medium" 
 sum(case WHEN cb.Priority = 3 THEN 1 else 0 end) as "High"  
 FROM TABLE 1 cb 
 LEFT JOIN Co c ON c.Id = cb.Id 
 WHERE c.Name LIKE %Name%" 
 GROUP BY c.name;
```